# I get previous float value when I am printing new value

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I am getting output `0.23` from second `printf`. But typecasting gives required output. If I am not using type casting previous value is printed.
Compiler version is GCC 6.3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%f ", 0.23);
    printf("%f", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

[LINK FOR IDE](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/hvBmV30S4F)

Comment: It is always good to read compiler warnings.

Comment: Enable more warnings with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`, the compiler will warn you about the argument type mismatch.

Comment: @LelouchTagami: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 6):

in

```
> printf("%f",0);
```

You ask to print a *double* but you give an *int*, this is contradictory

You are not in the case where the generated code makes a *double* from the *int* because *printf* is not `int printf(const char *, double);` but `int printf ( const char * format, ... );` and the compiler does not look at the format to make the necessary conversions ( but in a lot of cases the compiler warn you )

When *prints* access to the second argument is does to get a *double* using 64b and probably your *int* use only 32b, the behavior is undefined.

---

(edit, thank you @chqrlie)

> I get previous float value when i am printing new value

In your case may be *printf* retrieves a double value from the MMX registers as opposed to the *int* value that was passed via the stack or regular registers... which may explain why the same value gets printed twice. But of course as always with undefined behavior, anything else could happen at any time

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a combination of two factors:

The first is that for vararg functions like `printf`, the compiler will not do any implicit conversions of the arguments. So the `0` in the argument list is an *integer* constant (of type `int`).

The second factor is the mismatching format specifier. The `printf` function doesn't know *anything* about the arguments being passed, except what is specified in the format string. Mismatching format and argument type leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And since the `"%f"` specifier make `printf` expect a value of type `double`, and you have given an `int` value, you have such a mismatch.

Comment: @
Some programmer dude When I used GCC 4.3 in DevC++, I was getting 0.00.But in latest version i am not getting.

Comment: @LelouchYagami That's *undefined behavior* in action. You're lucky it didn't summon [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).